# Does Tweepy offer proxy support for Twitter API v2?

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I've looked through the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/index.html) but only found documentation indicating that Tweepy supports proxied requests through the v1 API. I have an essential developer account so I am limited to using the v2 API.
As a workaround, I wrote an API call in Python using the requests library as it does give me the ability to specify a proxy URL but in retrospect, I am now wondering if I could've done this with Tweepy after all. I'd be surprised if proxy support was removed from Tweepy for the v2 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy client uses requests `(requests.Session)` under the hood. You can inherit from the client and update/overwrite the session object to use proxies. Try this:

Solution 1. Subclassing tweepy.Client

```py
import tweepy


class Client(tweepy.Client):

    def __init__(self, proxies, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session.proxies = proxies
```

Solution 2. Using session object in tweepy.Client

```py
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(...)
client.session.proxies = {...}  # put your proxies here
```

Comment: There's no need to subclass `tweepy.Client` to do this.

Comment: i know, you can do it directly on the created object, check the edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tweepy.Client`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.14.0/client.html#tweepy.Client)'s [`session` attribute](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.14.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.session) and [configure proxies](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) through the [`requests.Session`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Session) it exposes.